# How to make specific types for seconds and milliseconds to avoid mixing them accidentally?

Tags: typescript

There is a function which receives some params, including *elapsed time*. I want TS to help the developers to *avoid a mistake* by calling it with milliseconds instead of seconds.

```js
function fn(foo: number, elapsedTime: seconds) {
  // ...
}

// I want the developer to set the second parameter in seconds
fn(1234, 3600 as seconds); // should pass
fn(1234, 3600000); // should fail
```

What are the best practices for that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a branded type for that.

```
type Seconds = number & { brands__ : 'seconds' };

function fn(foo: number, elapsedTime: Seconds) {
  // ...
}

fn(3000, 3000) // KO
fn(3000, 3000 as Seconds) // OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDGB7AdgEwM5QLxWQVwFsAjCAJygDIoBvKI0gQzXQH0WoAuKAcnQRQzcoAXwDcAKHEAzPMnjAAliihTkACimJEXfMTIAaKBAA2DMH1QAVBQQhc4SZgEoa4qFAD0HqADo-44UlVNQBmAAYIw3CIly8oAGkAeWl1aLCoiLCoBkwHAXRY70T4oA)

Comment: TY, it works for me 
Is there a particular reason why the type name it is capitalised?

Comment: its common for types to be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

typescript can't really handle something like "type Second = number" (like some other languages do).
So some tricks for this is that you encapsule value to object and have some type identity added like `{type: 'seconds', value: 3000}` or build those as classes so can be checked from "instanceof".